# How to download a file in parts

Tags: download, python-requests, python-3.3, urllib3

I'm writing a program that downloads files anywhere up to a 1Gb in size. Right now I'm using the requests package to download files, and although it works (I think it times out sometimes) it is very slow. I've seen some examples multi-part download examples using urllib2 but I'm looking for a way to use urllib3 or requests, if that package has the ability.

Answer (score 11):

How closely have you looked at requests' [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)?

In the [Quickstart documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) the following is described

```
r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
r.raw.read(amount)
```

The better way, however, to do this is:

```
fd = open(filename, 'wb')
r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
for chunk in r.iter_content(amount):
    fd.write(chunk)
fd.close()
```

(Assuming you are saving the downloaded content to a file.)

Comment: This is method I'm using to download files right now. And it's too slow, what I want to do is to be downloading parts of the file in parallel. Like thread1 0-200Mb and thread2 200Mb-size of file. Is this possible with requests or urllib3?

Comment: @user1704863 are you just processing them or are you trying to save them? You can run multiple downloads in parallel but I would not advise downloading individual chunks in parallel nor do I think you could seek ahead to start downloading a different part without losing everything before it.

Comment: It's possible, but requires you to learn how HTTP does this, using the HTTP Range header, combined with some Python threading. And then it's possible the server won't support it anyway.

Comment: @Lukasa Ya I think I've found how to go about it using range headers. Looking back over the requests documentation I missed the the part about the get headers part which solves my problem because the server does accept range headers

Comment: Process waits too long at `r = requests.get(url, stream=True)` but instantly finishes `for chunk in r.iter_content(amount): fd.write(chunk)` function. Is this code pre-downloading the file and splitting them or downloading specified part/chunk from web?

Comment: @user1704863 I got the same issue. Can you share your code? I need to download [this file of 26 GB](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/awsaf49/coco-2017-dataset/download)